# Livewire and Jetstream, can't call a blade component inside a blade component anymore, why?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I have a fresh Laravel 10 installation with livewire and Jetstream, have published the Jetstream assets.
I've created a new livewire component and the files were into **app\Livewire\SomeController.php** and the view at **resources\views\livewire** as usual.

These `resources\views\livewire\parent.blade.php` should call the `resources\views\livewire\child.blade.php`, but this is not working at all.
This is the way I always work, but it is not working anymore, why is that?

Let's see some code:

```
@livewire('chil', ['leadId' => $leadId])
```

And the error is that the component child can't be found